# Eclipse Plugin: Property tester never gets called

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to include a property tester variable in my plugin which checks a custom code condition and based on that returns a boolean value.
The property tester is used against a toolbar icon which is enabled and disabled based on property tester value.

Below is how I am declaring the property tester in my plugin.xml:-

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
    <propertyTester
        class="org.eclipse.intro.test.IsFoobarPropertyTester"
        id="org.eclipse.intro.IsFoobarPropertyTester"
        namespace="org.eclipse.test.FooBar"
        properties="isFooBar"
        type="java.lang.Object">
    </propertyTester>
</extension>
```

And below is how I am attaching the property tester to toolbar menu item:-

```
<toolbar id="org.eclipse.intro.FooToolbar">
    <command
          commandId="org.eclipse.intro.FooCommand"
          icon="intro/css/graphics/fooicon.png"
          tooltip="Foo Menu."
          id="org.eclipse.intro.FooCommand">
        <enabledWhen>
            <test property="org.eclipse.test.FooBar.isFooBar"
                  forcePluginActivation="true">
            </test>
        </enabledWhen>
    </command>
 </toolbar>
```

Now when I run the eclipse plugin, the property tester's test() never gets called. Even the constructor of property tester is getting called. Is there any configuraiton I have to do explicitly on eclipe to make it run?

Comment: Is the `toolbar` in the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point? Only `visibleWhen` is supported.

Comment: yes its under org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point. So should I replace enabledWhen with visibleWhen only i.e:-<visibleWhen>
            <test property="org.eclipse.test.FooBar.isFooBar"
                  forcePluginActivation="true">
            </test>
        </visibleWhen>

Comment: Thanks! it helped. Could you comment as answer so that I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point does not support `enabledWhen`. It only supports `visibleWhen`.